# How to parse 127.0.0.1:1234

Tags: python, urlparse

I am trying to parse `127.0.0.1:1234` with `urlparse`

```
urlparse('127.0.0.1:1234')
```

and it is giving me this result

```
ParseResult(scheme='127.0.0.1', netloc='', path='1234', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

I want `127.0.0.1` in `netloc` field.
How to do that?

Comment: It's not a valid URL so you basically get garbage in, garbage out. Did you mean `http://127.0.0.1:1234`?

Comment: def register_node(): values = request.form # 127.0.0.1:5002,127.0.0.1:5003,127.0.0.1:5004 nodes = values.get('nodes').replace(' ', '').split(',') if nodes is None: return 'Error: Please supply a valid list of nodes', 400 for node in nodes: blockchain.register_node(node) response = { 'message': 'Nodes have been added', 'total_nodes': [node for node in blockchain.nodes] } return jsonify(response), 200

Comment: def register_node(self, node_url): parsed_url = urlparse(node_url) if parsed_url.netloc: self.nodes.add(parsed_url.netloc) elif parsed_url.path: self.nodes.add(parsed_url.path) else: raise ValueError('Invalid URL')

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, posting code in comments is not the way to get there. If you are trying to clarify your question, [edit] it (but I doubt adding this code will make it any clearer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a scheme before the URL, `http` or `https`

```
URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:1234'
# Here http is the scheme and 127.0.0.1 is the netloc
parsed_obj = urlparse('http://127.0.0.1:1234')
print(parsed_obj)
# ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='127.0.0.1:1234', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: def register_node():
    values = request.form
    # 127.0.0.1:5002,127.0.0.1:5003,127.0.0.1:5004
    nodes = values.get('nodes').replace(' ', '').split(',')

    if nodes is None:
        return 'Error: Please supply a valid list of nodes', 400

    for node in nodes:
        blockchain.register_node(node)

    response = {
        'message': 'Nodes have been added',
        'total_nodes': [node for node in blockchain.nodes]
     }
    return jsonify(response),  200

Comment: def register_node(self, node_url):
        parsed_url = urlparse(node_url)
        if parsed_url.netloc:
            self.nodes.add(parsed_url.netloc)
        elif parsed_url.path:
            self.nodes.add(parsed_url.path)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid URL')

Comment: Adding your code, in the comment section doesn't help. You have to specify the problem you are facing by explaining the code you have written, what type of problem you are facing, and what results you would like to get from your code. Then others can help you solve your problem, also use StackOverflow documentation to write and format code, it will be helpful for others to read and solve your problem. Thank you